# Onclick multiple function calls issue, also sending previous click data

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with duplicate calls being sent onclick of a link, which includes the previous call data if they were made.

Here is the construction of the link in question.

```
for (var key in res) {
        var followers = res[key].followers;
        var totalposts = res[key].totalposts;
        var id = res[key].id;
        var name = res[key].name;
        var titles = "";
        titles = '<ul class="titles">';
        if (typeof res[key].titles === "object") {
            for (var index in res[key].titles) {
                var url = res[key].titles[index].st_url;
                titles += '<li><div class="ui grid"><div class="ui fourteen wide column">\u2022 <a href="'+url+'">'+url+'</a></div><div class="ui two wide column"><a title"Remove this post" href="#" onclick="showRemPost('+id+', \''+url+'\', \''+name+'\')" id="remPostButton"><i class="ui remove grey circle icon"></i></a></div></div></li>';
            }
        }
        titles += "</ul>";
        html += 
            '<div class="ui eight wide column"><div class="ui segment" data-id="' + id + '" id="list' + id + '">' +  
            '<div class="listTitle"><h4 class="left">' + name + '</h4><div class="right"><a href="#" id="editListButton" onclick="showEditList('+id+')"><i class="edit icon"></i></a>&nbsp;<a href="#" id="remListButton" onclick="showRemList('+id+', \''+name+'\')"><i class="remove icon"></i></a></div><div class="clear"></div></div>' + 
            '<div>' + titles + 
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="footList"><div class="left"><p>Followers: <span class="follow">'+followers+'</span>' + 
            '<br/>Posts: <span class="post">'+totalposts+'</span>' + 
            /*'<br/>Upvotes: <span class="upvote">'+res[key].upvotes+'</span>' + */
            '</p></div>' + 
            '<div class="right"><a href="#" onclick="showAddPost('+id+', \''+name+'\')" class="addPostButton"><i class="ui add blue circle icon"></i></div></div><div class="clear"></a></div>' +
            '</div></div>';
    }
```

Then I have this code for the function call:

```
showAddPost = function(id, lname){
    //do stuff
    console.log("\nshowAddPost function called");
}
```

`console.log("\nshowAddPost function called");` is showing 1 time on first click, then 2x on second click, and so on. Each time, I get the data from the previous click.

Since there are multiple links to click, any link clicked after another, will send all previous clicks and their data, as events to the `showAddPost`.

Ex: 1st click has "ID": "1" and "name": "One". These are sent. On the second link and second click, "ID": "2" and "name": "Two", which should only call once, and send only the Two data, but it sends the previous data, "1:One" to the function call `showAddPost`, then it send a second call to `showAddPost` for the actual link clicked with "2:Two". And the if I click on a third link, the same or different, it send the previous two data to the function.

Is the only way to resolve this by moving the `onclick` from the HTML to it's own `.on()` handler and then getting the data through `data-` attributes? Or can I get the data passed in an easier way with the .on() handler? Can I still use onclick and resolve this problem?

All of this is in a separate namespace, not global scope.

Thank you anyone for any help.

Comment: Actually, this shouldn't happen but, the possible reason may be you have a another click handler  function which is calling function again.

Comment: No, it's only called once in that HTML. But each time it calls it repeats all the previous calls and data they had sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely not closing the `a` tags.

So you end up with

```
<a href="#" onclick="showAddPost('+id+', \''+name+'\')" class="addPostButton">  
    <a href="#" onclick="showAddPost('+id+', \''+name+'\')" class="addPostButton">
        ...
```

Nesting `a` tags is invalid. The issue in your case is that the inner `a` tags will trigger all the previous since the click event bubbles upwards.

---

*update after updated code and comment*

Actually yes, the line

```
'<div class="right"><a href="#" onclick="showAddPost('+id+', \''+name+'\')" class="addPostButton"><i class="ui add blue circle icon"></i></div></div><div class="clear"></a></div>' +
```

has wrong matching on opening/closing tags. Lets break it down to see

```html
<div class="right">
  <a href="#" onclick="showAddPost('+id+', \''+name+'\')" class="addPostButton">
    <i class="ui add blue circle icon"></i>
    </div> <!-- << this here does not match a div, it should be an a -->
</div>
<div class="clear">
  </a> <!-- << this here probably belong on the previous group -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hehe, no. I edited the post with all the code so you can see. And I already checked all matching closing tags. View page source ;)

Comment: Oh damn, I suck, nice catch. I had tried semantic-ui floating but it was not working properly, so I went back to manual classes and messed up the changes back and cut off the a tag... eeek, sorry about that. Thank you for catching that. But the issue remains.
`<div class="right"><a href="#" onclick="showAddPost('+id+', \''+name+'\')" class="addPostButton"><i class="ui add blue circle icon"></i></a></div><div class="clear"></div>`

Comment: @KrNel can you post pastebin with the created html. Perhaps the data you pass mess up the html (*if there are `'` or `"` etc in any of the data you concatenate*)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zcLNtaQC
Is that what you are looking for? Thank you.

Comment: @KrNel it works fine at https://jsfiddle.net/418f086j/ so the error must be somewhere else. Do you have it live somewhere ?

Comment: OK here is a reduced version, on jsfiddle, and it does the same thing. 

https://jsfiddle.net/hchsjt8v/

Click the plus button to add, put in any chars, add, then close. Repeat. Check the console and you will see each one before gets done as well.

Comment: @KrNel that happens because on its call to `showAddPost` you run `$('#addPostConfirm').on("click", function(e) {` so you bind an additional handler each time.

Comment: Can you please link me to an explanation of this functionality that I don't understand? Thank you.

Comment: As a quick solution try `$('#addPostConfirm').off('click').on("click",...`

Comment: What the hell.  Thank you. I didn't know about this .off() method. Do you have a quick explanation as to what this is called? Why the off is required? Because there is more than one object attached to one event handler?

Comment: Or is this not the right way to do it? I didn't see another way to pass two vars from onlick without going to data- attributes. Should I do that instead? Thanks for the help.

Comment: That would be cleaner, but this is an equally valid way.